# JOIN queries not working in Node-postgres

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm trying to query two relational tables together using Node-PostgreSQL, but getting a syntax error:

```js
    ;(async () => {
        const client = await pool.connect()
        try {
          const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "Booking" JOIN "User" ON "User.id"="Booking.renter"')
          console.table(res.rows)
        } finally {
          client.release()
        }
      })().catch(err => console.log(err.stack))
```

The `Booking` table and the `User` table is joined by the `Booking.renter` column and the `User.id` column, but above code shows:

> error: column "User.id" does not exist

Querying a single table works fine:

```js
   const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "Booking"')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your `table.column` individually.

```
const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "Booking" JOIN "User" ON "User"."id"="Booking"."renter"')
```